# Can't connect to a device using react-native-bluetooth-classic

Tags: react-native, github, bluetooth

I am trying to send data from one android phone to another using "[react-native-bluetooth-classic](https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic)". I successfully run the example in the repo, but I am not able to connect to the paired devices. Sometimes, I can connect to a phone but the other can't connect back.

Is there any configuration I should to the phone's bluetooth?

Comment: There's nothing specific to phone to phone communication on the library. There is also not functionality for accepting connections (although there's been a pull request for it, I'm hesitant to pull it in at the moment). You can attempt to use that version, you can dind it through the github pull requests. With that said, if you're connecting to a device fine, I'd say that something very specific is. Kissing that I had never planned for. I've tested the app against windows and macs using app and both were successful.

Comment: There's actually a pull request pending that works with phone to phone. I'm waiting on a could things before merging.

Comment: @kendavidson can you let me know when you do the merging?

Comment: Probably won't be for another week.  I suggest if you need it, look the pull requests and find the fork which has this functionality.  If you can do some testing and see if its good (it looks good, but I don't have time to actually test it) and comment on the pull request with any issues. It would be a big help.

Comment: I will see what I can do. TBH, am still a newbie with react native, but I will do my best. Thnx.

Comment: This was literally my first React Native (React in general) project, so I feel ya.

Answer (score 2):

Merged the pull request last night, should be able to connect from one device to another with the provided `BluetoothClassicExample` app using the `Accept Connection` button at the bottom of the device list.

```
async acceptConnections() {
  console.log("App is accepting connections now...");
  this.setState({ isAccepting: true });

  try {
    let connectedDevice = await RNBluetoothClassic.accept();

    if (connectedDevice) {  // Undefined if cancelled
      this.setState({ connectedDevice, isAccepting: false });
    }      
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
    this.refs.toast.show(
      `Unable to accept client connection`,
      DURATION.LENGTH_SHORT
    );
    this.setSTate({ isAccepting: false });
  }
}
```

This is only available on **Android** as from what I've seen, there are no ways to see the connection on IOS.  I was able to connect my Android to my IOS using the example app, but without the Android MFi protocols, the data just gets sent into the IOS void.